# Where can I find the Invoice lines/details in DynamicsAX database?

Tags: sql-server, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-ax-2012

This is what I already know: 
Tables for open invoices: "CustTransOpen" - "CustInvoiceJour"

Now, I need some way to find all the lines that make up every single invoice. I've been researching and found that the tables `custInvoiceLine` and `custInvoiceBackorderLine` seem to hold this kind of information, but it's not exactly what I need.

Am I heading in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy way to find is go to form and see its data sources in AOT. In this case CustInvoiceJournal where you can see CustInvoiceJour and CustInvoiceTrans(Lines table) and related tables.